# OOP matter : Cannot call abstract method

Tags: php, oop, static, abstract, traits

I have a PHP core with an abstract class `AppBase` which use a trait `Uninstall`.
To force developper to implement a static function to delete some options inside the main class `MyApp`, the `AppBase` implements an interface with a static function 'delete_options()'.

**AppBase**

```
abstract class AppBase implements iUninstall{
     use Uninstall;
}
```

**Uninstall**

```
trait Uninstall{
    public static function uninstall(){
       //Do some general stuff
       self::delete_options();
    }
}
```

**iUninstall**

```
interface iUninstall {
    public static function delete_options();
}
```

**MyApp**

```
include_once "core/iUninstall.php";
include_once "core/Uninstall.php";
include_once "core/AppBase.php";

class MyApp extends AppBase{
   public static function delete_options() {
        delete_option( "first-option" );
        delete_option( "second-option" );
   }
}
```

My problem is I got this error:

> PHP Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Cannot call abstract method iUninstall::delete_options() in Uninstall.php

I can see the trait `Uninstall` must be attached to `AppBase` to use `delete_options` so there is a matter in my OOP architecture.

How can I resolve this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First off, you should have gotten a fatal error about `AppBase` having an abstract method `delete_options()` while not being an abstract class. So, you need to make `AppBase` an abstract class. (But perhaps you had just forgotten to copy that into your example.)

Then, in `Uninstall::uninstall()` you need to use `static` instead of `self` (to utilize [late static binding](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.late-static-bindings.php)).

So, to wrap it up:

```php
trait Uninstall {
  public static function uninstall(){
    // static instead of self
    static::delete_options();
  }
}

interface iUninstall {
  public static function delete_options();
}

// abstract class instead of class
abstract class AppBase implements iUninstall{
  use Uninstall;
}

class MyApp extends AppBase {
  public static function delete_options() {
    echo 'deleting';
  }
}

MyApp::uninstall();

/* result:
deleting
*/
```

Or... you could just implement `delete_options()` as a (stub) method in AppBase, but there was no indication in your question that that was your original intent.

[<sup>view online parsed @ eval.in</sup>](https://eval.in/1039997)

Comment: I'd love to hear the motivation behind the down-vote my answer received.

Comment: @Decente Dabbler - Me too.

Comment: @Decente Dabbler I edit my answer, yes I forgot to add the `abstract` word before the class.